# Google spreadsheets Script que genera formulas que hacen referencia a intervalos con nombre

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

tengo un problema con la generación de formulas en celdas mediante scripts.
Apartir de un spreadsheet, genero nuevas sheets ("sesion" y "dist.sesion") ademas de copiar otra sheet de otro spreadsheet. También creo en la sheet "sesion" un rango con nombre "Participaciones" (sesion!Participaciones) que inicialmente esta no tiene valores. A este intervalo le asigno una validación de datos para que me despliegue una lista.

Bien, en la sheet de "Dist.sesion", en una celda asigno una formula mediante:

`fD.getRange(fil+2,col+1,).setFormula('=COUNTIF(Participaciones;"Cap d\'aula")');`

cuando se ejecuta el escript se generan todos los sheets, intervalos con nombre, y demás elementos pero no me cuenta las apariciones del literal "Cap d'aula" dentro del intervalo, en la celda de la sheet aparece 0. Si miro la formula que me ha generado, me aparece `=COUNTIF(Participaciones;"Cap d'aula")` si lo edito directamente en la celda y pongo `=COUNTIF(Participaciones;"=Cap d'aula")` ya me lo calcula bien, si lo vuelvo a cambiar a `=COUNTIF(Participaciones;"Cap d'aula")` también me lo calcula bien. Da la sensación de que la formula generada por el script no se crea bien. Es este proyecto he creado muchas formulas desde script y no he tenido nigún problema, la unica diferencia es el uso de un intervalo con nombre. No he encontrado ejemplos o informacion de como crear formulas que usen intervalos con nombre.

Alguien me puede echar un cable con este problema.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 1):

Ya lo tengo resuelto. El problema consistia en que creaba la formula con la referencia al intervalo con nombre antes de crear el intervalo.